# I cant start a timer 2 times

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm making a timer in Java and I need help. There is a swing timer added to the main class. I have a jFrame which has 2 panels, 1 having the jLabel, the other one having 3 buttons, "Start", "Stop" and "Reset". When I click start then everything is working fine and when I stop then reset. But when I click on start again, it pumps out this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already                                       cancelled.
at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Timer.schedule(Unknown Source)
at org.stopwatch.Stopwatch.start(Stopwatch.java:71)
at org.stopwatch.Stopwatch$1.actionPerformed(Stopwatch.java:48)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my code:
    package org.stopwatch;

```
import static javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName;
import static javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Stopwatch {

private static boolean running = false;
public static int time = 0;
public static Timer timer = new Timer();
public static JLabel leftLabel = new JLabel(time + "s");

public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    setLookAndFeel(getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(1, 1);
    f.setTitle("Секундомір");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    f.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    leftPanel.add(leftLabel);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    f.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JButton startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    JButton stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
    JButton resetBtn = new JButton("Reset");
    buttonPanel.add(startBtn);
    buttonPanel.add(stopBtn);
    buttonPanel.add(resetBtn);
    startBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            running = true;
            start();
        }
    });
    stopBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            running = false;
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });
    resetBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            if(!running) {
                time = 0;
                leftLabel.setText("0s");
            }
        }
    });
    f.pack();
}

public static void start() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            time++;
            leftLabel.setText(time + "s");
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is in the error message. It says you can't start a timer that has been cancelled. You will have to create a new `Timer` using the `new` operator.

Do this in your `start()` function.

`timer = new Timer();`

If you decide to go this route, don't forget to remove the `new` operation from your declaration. You will overwrite the assignment in your `start()` function.

`public static Timer timer;`

If you want to store the time between runs, you need to do that before you overwrite the timer with a new one.

Comment: Thanks. i renewed the timer in the start method. Its working now!

Comment: @user2564491 Why are you using a `java.util.Timer`? You should be using `javax.swing.Timer` for Swing apps, as seen [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21619240/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet If `java.util.Timer` satisfies his needs, he should definitely use it. If he needed his timer to update his GUI, then he should use `javax.swing.Timer`. However, the opposite is true - his GUI is updating his timer, in which case there is no reason to use the swing timer.

Comment: @peeskillet You seem to be confusing _updating the GUI_ with _displaying the timer in the GUI_. His timer isn't firing off events, showing and hiding elements, and doing other GUI manipulations. Displaying a time is not the same as firing events on a timer. Just so we are clear, `setText()` is a function of the Label, NOT the timer. If that isn't clear enough, imagine you wanted to display an integer in your GUI. Would you use some swing variable for that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's behaving exactly as documented. As per the [`cancel()` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29):

> Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.

And as per the documentation of the `schedule` methods:

> `IllegalStateException` - if task was already scheduled or cancelled, timer was cancelled, or timer thread terminated.

Basically, you'll need to create a new `Timer` on each `start` operation - or just don't cancel the existing one, changing the `run` method of your `TimerTask` to ignore operations when the timer is logically stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new timer on `start()` and fill it with the time from the 'old' timer.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550561/pause-the-timer-and-then-continue-it)

Answer (score 0):

When you call timer.cancel(), then the timer thread will be stop!
you may stop some task, but not the timer! when the timer is canceled,you have to new a tiemr!

you can look [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/452066/java/java/Exception-timer-IllegalStateException)