# Updating JTextField every second

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

I have this simple GUI for a time registration application

[image: gui]

As the GUI is used for time registration, I'd like it to show a timer that runs as you press "Start" until you press "Stop".

Currently the two methods are done like this:

```
private void trStartBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    trStartBtn.setEnabled(false);
    trStopBtn.setEnabled(true);

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
}                                          

private void trStopBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    trStartBtn.setEnabled(true);
    trStopBtn.setEnabled(false);
    // Opgave Navn
    String taskName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            this,
            "Task name",
            "Time Registration",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    // Tiden det tog
    long result = endTime - startTime;
    double seconds = (double) result / 1000000000;
    int minutes = (int)seconds / 60;
    int hours = minutes / 60;
    String time = hours + ";" + minutes + ";" + (int) seconds;

    // Dags Dato
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date today = new Date();
    String date = format.format(today);

    DefaultTableModel m = (DefaultTableModel)trTable.getModel();
    Object[] data = {date,time,taskName};
    m.addRow(data);
    trScrollPane.repaint();
}
```

But how would I add functionality so that the timer up to the right will tick every second as to show the time as you use the program? It's been a while and I am a bit rusty at Swing. I know that making a thread to take care of it is not safe.

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21619240/2587435) or the one [below it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21619465/2587435) using a `JLabel`

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the update of the label every second.

When you click the Start button you start the Timer and when you click the Stop button you stop the Timer.

Comment: Even though jtextfield.setText() doesn't need repaint/validation to work?

Comment: @Vipar Swing components are smart enough to revalidate/repaint themselves when a property (like setText()) is invoked. Why are you using a JTextField. A text field is for entering text. I would think you only want to display text.

Comment: What else would I use to show the time as the timer is running?